# load knockout.js lib at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, knockout.js

I want to load knockout.js lib at run time. It gets loaded but after applyBindings() the html body tag i.e `<body></body>` disappers and throws

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of null

```
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        script.setAttribute("src", "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js");
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

I just dont understand, why the body element gets emptied.
**P.S. :** It works perfectly, if I add  knockout.js lib beforehand.

Comment: `script.setAttribute("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js", url);` - is this right?

Comment: sorry. that was by mistake, see the updated QUestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're using `ko` without making sure that the script is already loaded. You need to pass a *callback* using the `onload` property:

```
script.onload = function() {
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
}
```

Also, Knockout complains because you're calling `applyBindings` before the DOM is ready. Try to run your code as part of a `DOMContentLoaded` event callback:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { 
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    script.setAttribute("src", "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js");
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

    script.onload = function() {
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    }
});
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/urvoz2z8/)

Comment: I solved it. Actually, that was not the issue, I was using 'document.write()' to append the scripts to the head tag. But, it was creating new documnet (DOM) so the whole HTML DOM appeared to be empty. Well, but I'm going to accept yours as a answer though. As, it is right as per the question.